# django-environ dictionary format

Tags: python, django

I'm having a difficult time trying to understand how to write data to the .env file as to get a dictionary.

The [docs](https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#django-environ) say this:

```
dict (BAR=key=val;foo=1.1;baz=True) #environ.Env(BAR=(dict(value=unicode, 
cast=dict(foo=float,baz=bool)), {}))
```

In my .env file i have something like this

```
EMAIL=host=xx;port=xx;user=xx;pass=xx;tls=True
```

However, i really don't know what to pass to the casting in the settings.py file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In casting up the .env file vars in settings file one need this structure for dictionaries for this particula case:

```
env = environ.Env(
      EMAIL=({
                'cast':{
                    'host':str,
                    'port':int,
                    'user':str,
                    'pass':str,
                    'tls':bool,
                }
               }, {})
    )
```

If an empty dictionary is supplied, then all the values will be cast as strings.

Answer (score 8):

Two ways:

*.env*

```
DATA={"hello":"world"}
```

*main.py*

```py
env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()

# Get the data

data = env.json("DATA")

type(data) # dict
```

---

*.env*

```
DATA=hello=world,hello2=world2
```

*main.py*

```py
env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()

# Get the data

data = env.dict("DATA")

type(data) # dict
```

Comment: How about nested dicts ?

Comment: It's the same thing. Once you get your dictionary you can iterate through the elements and thus nested them

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

ENV:

```
# The value of the mockup user
AAA_MOCKUP_USER_OBJ={'is_authenticated'=True,'id'=888,'username'="sasha_test",'firstName'="Sasha",'lastName'="Rudan"}
```

`common.py`:

```py
print(f"[common] AAA_MOCKUP_USER_OBJ={AAA_MOCKUP_USER_OBJ}")
```

printes well:

```
[common] AAA_MOCKUP_USER_OBJ={"{'is_authenticated'": 'True', "'id'": '888', "'username'": '"sasha_test"', "'firstName'": '"Sasha"', "'lastName'": '"Rudan"}'}
```